# C++ Lookup hostname for IP without #include <winsocket2.h>

Tags: c++, ip, hostname

How can i retrieve the IP related to a hostname without `#include <winsocket2.h>`?
I can't use the `<winsocket2.h>` methods because my DLL crashs without any compile errors, the following code doesn't work ...

```
hostent *h = gethostbyname(hostName);
      LogAlways((const char*)inet_ntoa(*(reinterpret_cast<in_addr*>(h->h_addr))));
```

Comment: give us more code - there's definitely omething you are doing wrong but you blame winsocket

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2008 express edition, yeah it's not my own DLL.. the type of hostName is const char*, the function LogAlways allows it

Comment: What is the *value* of `hostName`? Verify that it's what you think it should be using a debugger. And after that line, check what's stored in `h` - it could well be a null pointer if an error occurred (e.g. the host lookup failed). That would pretty well guarantee that your next line would fail one way or another. You need to gracefully handle the failure, not assume it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Without an include (or a dependency on an external library) there's *almost* no way.

In order to get the hostname that maps to an IP you need to do a RARP request which pretty much requires you to be able to use sockets. So one way or another you need to be able to create a socket. Which is what the winsock2.lib provides as a library.

So, you're better off getting winsock2.lib to work. When you say your DLL crashes without any compile errors I'm assuming you are talking about your own code which you're trying to compile into a DLL.

What about debugging? Have you tried stepping through the code to see where it fails? What is the type of hostName? Check to make sure you're not trying to access members on a null pointer. And that you've allocated memory correctly before you're using the variables. Otherwise, let us know more specifically what error message you get in the debugger.

Comment: You can call functions from `ws2_32.dll` using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.  `#include` is not necessary.  `winsock2.lib` is not necessary.  And the program has a chance to recover from missing functions on old versions of Windows.

Comment: Yeah, Ben's right.. what I meant to say is that you can't really get away without a dependency on an external library. Whether it is winsock2 or something else..